# Junit test case not running for mock JPA

Tags: junit, mockito

I have written sample CRUD methods.I have written JUnit test cases for Service component but getting "address id not found.." when I run the test.

@Test
public void updateAddressTest() throws ResourceNotFoundException {

```
        Optional<Person> p = Optional.ofNullable(new Person( "Pranya", "Pune"));
        when(personRepository.existsById(1L)).thenReturn(true);
        
        
        Optional<Address> address = Optional.ofNullable(new Address( "zzz", "hyd","tel","1234"));
        
        when(repository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(address);
        
        Address addr1 = new Address( "zzz", "hyd","tel","1234");
        when(repository.save(addr1)).thenReturn(addr1);
        Address add= service.updateAddress(new Long(1L), new Long(1L),addr1);
        
        assertEquals(addr1,add );
    }





@Service
public class AddressService {

@Autowired
    private AddressRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

public Address updateAddress(Long personId,
             Long addressId,Address addrRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        
         if (!personRepository.existsById(personId)) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("personId not found");
            }

         return repository.findById(addressId).map(address -> {
                address.setCity(addrRequest.getCity());
                address.setState(addrRequest.getState());
                address.setStreet(addrRequest.getStreet());
                address.setPostalCode(addrRequest.getPostalCode());
                Person p = new Person();
                p.setId(personId);
                address.setPerson(p);
                
                return repository.save(address);
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("address id not found.."));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `repository.save(address)` returns `null`. You are mocking the method, but only for the argument equal `addr1`. Inside the AddressService a different instanceof the address is created. I'm guessing that Address class does not implement `equals` method (or includes the person field in the implementation), so `when(repository.save(addr1)).thenReturn(addr1)` does not match the call and `null` is returned.

To solve the problem try using `Mockito.doAnswer` instead of the `Mockito.when`:

```java
Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> invocation.getArguments()[0]).when(repo).save(Mockito.any(Address.class));
```

Comment: the problem is with this line:Address add= service.updateAddress(new Long(1L), new Long(1L),addr1);

Comment: @user739115 This line looks  ok to me. The problem is with the way you are mocking the AddressRepository (or with the AddressService implementation). See my edited answer.